# Sharing configuration between several VHosts

Tags: apache, configuration, web-config, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I'm managing a httpd installation with several sites running on it, each defined within it's own `<VirtualHost>` directive. There are several configuration variables (most of them from [core](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html) as well as some `php_flag`/`php_value`) that are exactly the same for several of the sites defined.

I would like to be able to define a configuration set that will apply to several `<VirtualHost>` directives at the same time (to remove redundancy and make the server maintenance a little bit easier).

I have considered using `<Directory>`, however many of the configuration values I need to set, cannot be modified from within `<Directory>`. I have also tried to define another `<VirtualHost>` section, containing all of the sites I want to share the config in

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80 yy.yy.yy.yy:80>
    ...config...
</VirtualHost>
```

but this just results in

```
VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80 overlaps with VirtualHost yy.yy.yy.yy:80, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In apache documentation this is called [mass VirtualHost configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html).

Several solutions exists:

- [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html), with the `VirtualDocumentRoot` instructions, but it is usually too simple and managing other variations than `DocumentRoot` and the domain name  are quite hard.
- [advanced mod_rewrite tricks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/vhosts.html), as mod_rewrite is a swiss knife and can do everything, but everything seems quite complex when it is done with mod_rewrite.
- [mod_macro](http://www.cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/mod_macro/) is a module that allow the usage of an infinite list of macros with parameters that can be reused between Virtualhosts (for example), so you can add more parameters than `DocumentRoot` and `ServerName` and share single configurations files between serval Vhosts.