# Override single setting in default Apache <VirtualHost> block

Tags: apache, vhosts

In debian's default apache2 configuration, `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` contains a lot of settings for the default VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Many good settings here, among them:
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
</VirtualHost>
```

In another configuration file, I'd like to override a single one of them, the `CustomLog` setting, so that logs go somewhere else. I don't want to copy or mess with all the other settings, e.g. `ScriptAlias`. But I still want it to apply to `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

Is that possible?

### What I tried

I tried putting this in 
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-mylog`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

That has no effect, presumably because apache only looks at the first `<VirtualHost>` section, and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` gets loaded before `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-mylog`.

Instead I tried putting the same snippet in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/mylog`, that gets loaded before `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` because `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` has an `Include conf.d/` before `Include sites-enabled/`. That does override the `CustomLog` value as I wanted. But now the `ScriptAlias` from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` doesn't take effect.

I'd like to avoid duplicating everything from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` effectively creating a fork of the default debian apache configuration file.

### Documentation

[Apache HTTP Server - core documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#virtualhost) has this rather vague:

> When a request is received, the server first maps it to the best matching
>    based on the local IP address and port combination only.
>   Non-wildcards have a higher precedence. If no match based on IP and port occurs
>   at all, the "main" server configuration is used.
>
> If multiple virtual hosts contain the best matching IP address and port, the
>   server selects from these virtual hosts the best match based on the requested
>   hostname. If no matching name-based virtual host is found, then the first
>   listed virtual host that matched the IP address will be used. As a consequence,
>   the first listed virtual host for a given IP address and port combination is
>   default virtual host for that IP and port combination.

### `<VirtualHost>` doesn't behave like `<Directory>`

Very confusingly, it looks to me as if for `<VirtualHost>` directives, only a single matching instance is considered. But for e.g. `<Directory>` directives, they are added/combined, so that:

```
<Directory "/some/dir">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
<Directory "/some/dir">
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<Directory "/some/dir">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But that this mechanism doesn't work for `<VirtualHost>` :-(

**Edit**: This is not the same as [Sharing configuration between several VHosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714293/sharing-configuration-between-several-vhosts), because debian's default VirtualHost doesn't use any of those solutions. But perhaps others can find inspiration in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same puzzle for the multiple vhosts'(virtual hosts') definition. Do they override(redefine), overlap? Or there are other veiled details inside?

I find some links for this puzzle as following:
   https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/
   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

With cautions to these examples inside, I could say the vhosts' definitions are not the same (even they look like the same). The difference mainly lays on the ***SeverName*** inside definition. Apache httpd server distinguishes the different vhost definitions based on ***ServerName*** inside(each vhost definition), **not** the IP Address or Port Number as listed in the `<VirtualHost>` header.

This puzzle keeps coming and going since there lacks explicit explanation for this topic(in the web). I hope this post can help to relieve this mindboggler in a way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though I must admit I don't know what to make of it - I don't understand what you mean. E.g. I don't mention ServerName at all in my example. How does it answer my question: "In another configuration file, I'd like to override a single one of them, the CustomLog setting... Is that possible?"

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, too busy on my project recently. What I mean is: <virtual host> Header does not work alone, it works together with ServerName value inside. Hence, to distinguish different  virtual hosts definitions, one has to check both of them. That's why virtual host definition behaves different from that of directory.